# Magento2: how to move a block

Tags: layout, magento2

I am exploring Magento 2 for the 1st time (I am not familiar with Magento 1 either).
I manage to figure out how the static blocks work but cannot find out how certain blocks work.

- For example how the layered navigation block is setup?
- How can i change the position of that block?